# Getting file name in ruby where method was called

Tags: ruby

I have a method `foo` and it is called in a script `script001.rb`
how should I write the `foo` method so that it returns the file name of a script that called it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Kernel#caller`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) which returns the current execution stack — an array containing strings in the form `file:line` or `file:line: in 'method'`:

```
def foo
  caller[0][/[^:]+/]  # OR  caller[0].split(':')[0]
end
```

Answer (score 12):

To avoid needing to deal with `caller` style strings, you can use [`Kernel#caller_locations`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-caller_locations), instead. It returns you an array of [`Thread::Backtrace::Location`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html) objects, which has some convenient methods available for you.

To get the filename, in your case, you can use the `#path` method:

```
def foo
  caller_locations.first.path
end
```

Comment: There is also an `absolute_path` method on `Thread::Backtrace::Location` if you want the full path to the file.

Answer (score 7):

@falsetru's answer is correct, but I thought I'd add this bit of code to demonstrate the different outputs of the methods proposed.

Two files.

**hosting.rb**

```
class Hosting
  def self.foo
    puts "__FILE__: #{__FILE__}"
    puts "__method__: #{__method__}"
    puts "caller: #{caller}"
    puts "caller_locations.first.path: #{caller_locations.first.path}"
  end
end
```

**calling.rb**

```
require_relative 'hosting'
Hosting.foo
```

**On:** `ruby calling.rb` the output is:

```
__FILE__: /path/to/hosting.rb
__method__: foo
caller: ["calling.rb:2:in `<main>'"]
caller_locations.first.path: calling.rb
```